# How come twitter's since & until params won't work?

Tags: api, search, date, twitter, range

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=twitter+since%3A2010-01-01+until%3A2010-01-01
I tried to search for the term "twitter" between 2010-01-01 to 2011-01-01 and it won't return any results, anyone know why? If I do a recent time range it works.

Answer (score 3):

The search API only returns results from roughly the previous four days, that's why you aren't getting any data. Your query is perfectly valid; just modify the dates to be within the last four days.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter+since%3A2011-07-01+until%3A2011-07-01

- or for more human-readable results

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=twitter+since%3A2011-07-01+until%3A2011-07-01